# Debugging VB6 in VS2008 with non-VB6 objects

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2008, com, vb6

I have a C# EXE project that references a C++ dll and a VB6 dll.

I can successfully step into the C++ from C# in Visual Studio 2008 when I open the corresponding files.

I achieved the same ability to step into the VB6 from C# by generating a PDB file when compiling the VB6 dll.

The issue I have is that when debugging into the VB6 DLL, any .NET and C++ objects show as `<void>` in the 'locals' and 'watch' windows.

Is it expecting too much to be able to evaluate objects across 3 languages in the one IDE?

Or is there an alternative solution?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It is not entirely clear from your question what undesirable behaviour you are experiencing and what behaviour you are expecting instead.

Comment: Undesirable behaviour is objects value showing as <void> in the watch window. Likewise objectname.objectproperty will not evalute.

Desirable behavior is for objects value to show up in the watch window, and expressions to evalute eg MailItem.Subject will return "TheSubject"

Answer (score -1):

VB6 was developed before .Net was released and so it would have no understand of .Net references. Even if the .Net objects were available to VB6 as COM objects, I don't think VB6 has ability to allow you to examine them at debug time.

Comment: I think he's using the VS2008 debugger. If the .Net objects are really pretending to be COM objects, you might expect to be able to view them in the debugger just like any other COM object.